# SQLite to Postgres Hierarchy Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

Here's a query I have successfully used with SQLite. It creates a hierarchy of all links that belong to a "Pak".

```
WITH LinkTree(link_id, link_pid, pak_id, link_name, depth)
AS
(
SELECT *, 0 AS depth FROM links
WHERE link_pid = 0

UNION ALL
SELECT l.*, lt.depth+1 AS depth FROM LinkTree lt
JOIN links l ON (lt.link_id = l.link_pid)
)
SELECT * FROM LinkTree WHERE pak_id = 1;
```

I am trying to modify it so it works with Postgres, but I am getting an error saying that "depth" is ambigious.

There are two simple tables used:

```
Paks: pak_id, pak_name
Links: link_id, link_pid, link_name, pak_id
```

All columns are integers, except the *_name's that are varchars.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `RECURSIVE` keyword:

```
WITH RECURSIVE LinkTree(link_id, link_pid, pak_id, link_name, depth)
AS
(
SELECT *, 0 AS depth FROM links
WHERE link_pid = 0

UNION ALL
SELECT l.*, lt.depth+1 AS depth FROM LinkTree lt
JOIN links l ON (lt.link_id = l.link_pid)
)
SELECT * FROM LinkTree WHERE pak_id = 1;
```

**EDIT:**

Do not use `*` in select:

```
WITH LinkTree(link_id, link_pid, pak_id, link_name, depth)
AS
(
  SELECT link_id, link_pid, pak_id, link_name, 0 AS depth 
  FROM links
  WHERE link_pid = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT l.link_id, l.link_pid, l.pak_id, l.link_name, lt.depth+1 AS depth 
  FROM LinkTree lt
  JOIN links l 
    ON lt.link_id = l.link_pid
)
SELECT * 
FROM LinkTree 
WHERE pak_id = 1;
```

Comment: You are right, but its not enough. I have tried that, but there are many more error messages coming up after that. Maybe you can spot some more faults with this query?

Comment: @kapibara Without table structure and data no. And you can post error message because I cannot see your screen

Comment: @kapibara: **edit** your question and add the **exact** error message you get (and yes, the keyword `recursive` is required)

Comment: After re-creating the tables and running the query with RECURSIVE it now seems it might work. Not 100% sure, will test some more and keep you posted.

Comment: Lo and behold. With RECURSIVE added it just works. I suspect though, that the table "Links" has to have its columns in the same order as the columnlist on line one above.